# Find the equation of the plane in both Cartesian and (vector) parametric form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Find the plane through the point $(1,4,5)$ and perpendicular to the vector $(7,1,4)$.

Answer given to me is 
$$7x + y + 4z = 31 \text{  (I get this).}$$

and $$r = (1,4,5) + s(4,0,-7) + t(0,4,-1)$$ (I tried but couldn't get the middle vector with 's').

Comment: Please see [this MathJax basic tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to format your maths properly. Also, what are $r$, $s$ and $t$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) and the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two vectors are picked such that they are perpendicular to the normal vector $(7,1,4)$. For them to be perpendicular, their dot product is zero.

We can see easily, the dot product of $(4,0,-7)$ and $(7,1,4)$ is $4\cdot 7+0 \cdot 1+(-7)\cdot 4=0$. You can pick any vector that has one element equal to, and another element opposite to the corresponding ones in $(7,1,4)$, switch their positions, and leave the 3rd one $0$. For example, $(-1,7,0), (1,-7,0),(-4,0,7), (0,4,-1),(0,-4,1)$.